# Identity Matrix - only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm doing Identity Matrix, but it comes TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index, and IDK how to fix it, plz help me!

```
Z = np.array([
[0,2,0,4,4],
[0,0,3,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0],
[0,2,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0]
])

I = np.eye(Z)
I = np.identity(Z)
```

Both np.eye and np.identify come to the same error.

Comment: What exactly is your intended output with `I = np.eye(Z)`? A matrix of how many dimensions and with how many elements in each dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fucntion `np.identity()` takes an integer argument, not `np.array()` object as argument. So if you want to create an identity matrix of size `nxn` you need to calculate the length of `Z`:

```
import numpy as np

Z = np.array([
[0,2,0,4,4],
[0,0,3,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0],
[0,2,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0]
])


I = np.identity(len(Z))
print(I)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```